# This operation requires an interactive window station

Tags: c#, console-application

I am getting this error when trying to call a program from a program that is called by a scheduled task.

```
 private static void CallProgram(int jobID, int productID)
    {
        DataTable dtProduct = GetProductInformation(productID);

        try
        {
            // 1
            // Initialize process information.
            //
            ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
            p.WorkingDirectory = string.Format(@"{0}", dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProgramDirectory"].ToString());
            p.FileName = dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProgramName"].ToString();
            // 2
            // add arguments
            string[] args = { jobID.ToString() };
            p.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
            p.UseShellExecute = true;
            p.Verb = "runas";
             //p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // 3.
            // Start process and wait for it to exit
            //
            Process x = Process.Start(p);
            //x.WaitForExit();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string function = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            ErrorHandling(function, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I currently have a windows service that does this operation. however I have found that it sometimes hangs. I have built an console application that does exactly the same thing the service does. my thought was to put it on a task scheduler so it runs on the set interval. similar to to the windows service. However when I run the program from the scheduler I receive the following error

> WorkOnQueue Error: This operation requires an interactive window
> station Stack Trace: at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo) at RenkimAutomation.Program.CallProgram(Int32 jobID, Int32
> productID) at RenkimAutomation.Program.WorkOnQueue() MachineName:
> PROD-SERVICES Time Stamp: 3/7/2016 6:11:04 PM

I cannot figure out how to get around this error. Please help

Comment: Can you try running your application in admin mode

Comment: the scheduled task is set to run with the highest privileges.

Comment: I can't verify it right now, but I don't think `WindowStyle` is the parameter on `ProcessStartInfo` that you want.  Look into `CreateNoWindow`.

Comment: @object88 I modified the program to use CreateNoWindow = true. however i am still receiving the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of " p.UseShellExecute = true; " from your code because it requires the user to manually choose 'Yes' or 'No' to enable execution as an Administrator. Instead, in the Task Scheduler, select the execution user to be an administrator and then inside your code execute the Process as administrator by using: p.Verb = "runas";

So the modified Code looks like:

```
private static void CallProgram(int jobID, int productID)
{
    DataTable dtProduct = GetProductInformation(productID);

    try
    {
        // 1
        // Initialize process information.
        //
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.WorkingDirectory = string.Format(@"{0}", dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProgramDirectory"].ToString());
        p.FileName = dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProgramName"].ToString();
        // 2
        // add arguments
        string[] args = { jobID.ToString() };
        p.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args);
        p.Verb = "runas";
         //p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // 3.
        // Start process and wait for it to exit
        //
        Process x = Process.Start(p);
        //x.WaitForExit();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string function = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        ErrorHandling(function, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```